# Using a W Beam on its Side

Tags: joists

We are attempting to span 16' and replace a load bearing wall holding up the plaster ceiling and low slope roof.
I would like to use a steel W Beam mounted sideways to minimize intrusion into the room ceiling.
What is the continuous load load derating if the beam is on its side?

Comment: The size of the steel you are thinking about has everything to do with its strength. Is a w beam 2 channels welded together? We do a lot of steel work at my plant and I am only an electrician but I have not heard of a W beam. But most beams get there strength by there width so laying it on its side it may have very little strength.

Comment: That's just a bad idea. No one is likely to have that information anyway since they're not intended for such use.

Comment: @EdBeal A "W-beam" is a wide-flange beam, very similar to an I-beam. Despite the rude title, this page explains it nicely -- http://steelhouseindy.com/its-w-beam-not-i-beamyou-dummy/ . And yep, turning it on its side vastly reduces the usable strength.

Comment: I have never heard them called anything other than H or I @doug but thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

A “W Shape” steel beam is the wrong shape. It’s nearly as wide as tall.

I’d try a “S Shape” steel beam. They are “skinny” and can be installed in the wall correctly (vertically).

Give us an idea of the load and we can give a size. (A S8 will support about 14 kips for a 16’ span and has a flange width of 4”.)

Answer (score 1):

I estimate you'll need a beam with a size in the range as shown in the table below.

To compare the "derating" due to laying on the sideway of a select beam, you simply compare Iy (weak) with Ix (strong), and Sy with Sx.

For example, let's say you need W8x10:

Iy/Ix = 2.1/30.3 = 0.0693, and Sy/Sx = 1.1/7.8 = 0.141. The former case governs, and the percentage of derating (loss of capacity) equals to (100 - 1/0.0693)% = 86%

[image]